# HTML how to validate any of checkbox which are in Array before submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, checkbox

Below is the HTML/PHP code, in which i need to validate any of the checkbox out of 5 before submit the Form.

```js
function checkAddress(checkbox)
{
    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
document.frmUser.submit();
    }

else {alert("checkbox");}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Details Form</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function checkAddress(checkbox)
{
    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
document.frmUser.submit();
    }

else {alert("checkbox");}
}
</script>      
</head>

<body>

<div class="form-style-1">
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<?php
i=0;
while(i=5){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo i; ?>" >
<input type="button" name="update" class="button" value="Update" onClick="checkAddress(this);" />
<?php
$i++;}
?>
</form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to test that at least one of the checkboxes is checked, and if not prevent the submission?

Comment: what is this `while(i=5)`? A condition is never given like that. It sholud be `while(i<=5)`.

Comment: yes , at least one of the checkboxes is checked, and if not prevent the submission?

Comment: your html is missing the opening `html` tag btw

Comment: Sorry my mistake , actual code is `while(i<=5)`

Comment: is their any other way to validate checkbox which are in array as in my code. ` function checkAddress(checkbox)` is read but everytime alert is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this

```js
function checkAddress(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
    //document.frmUser.submit();
  } else {
    document.frmUser.action = "#";
    alert("checkbox");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-1">
  <form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
    <?php $i=0; while($i<=5){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" onClick="checkAddress(this);" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">

    <?php $i++;} ?>
    <input type="submit" name="update" class="button" value="Update" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Some errors in your code

- you have not used `$` while denoting the variable `i`
- you are taking the `button` inside the `while` loop so it also repeating with the checkboxes.

Comment: below is my update code. it works great !!..Thanks guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `onClick="checkAddress(this);"` from your *button*, so `this` refers to the button and *not* a checkbox, so then in your function `checkbox.checked` is testing if the *button* is checked - which obviously it never will be.

To test whether at least one checkbox is checked you could loop through them testing them in turn, but you can also do it in one step as follows:

```
if (document.querySelector('form[name="frmUser"] input[name="users[]"]:checked')) {
  // at least one is checked
}
```

The [`.querySelector()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first matching element (which is a truthy value for use in an `if` test), or returns `null` if no matching elements are found (which is a falsey value for use in an `if` test).

(If the page has only one form with one group of checkboxes then you could simplify the selector to something like `.querySelector(':checked')`, but I think it is better to be explicit about which items you're testing.)

In context:

```js
function checkAddress()
{
    if (document.querySelector('form[name="frmUser"] input[name="users[]"]:checked')) {
        alert("Success! (form would be submitted here)");
        //document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
        //document.frmUser.submit();
    } else {
        alert("You must select at least one checkbox");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-1">
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="2" >
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="3" >
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="4" >
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="5" >
<input type="button" name="update" class="button" value="Update" onClick="checkAddress();" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another problem with the code posted - the variable `i` wasn't correctly defined ~ it should have been `$i`

Rather than assigning the function directly to the button you can create an event listener like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Details Form</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function validate(e){
                var form=e.target.parentNode;
                var col=form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
                var checked=[];
                if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ){
                    if( col[n].checked ) checked.push( col[n].name );
                }
                if( checked.length > 0 ){
                    form.action='edit_user.php';
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    alert('You MUST tick at least one checkbox');
                }
            }
            function bindEvents(){
                var bttn=document.forms['frmUser'].querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')[0];
                    bttn.addEventListener( 'click', validate, false );
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
        </script>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-style-1">
            <form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
            <?php
                $i=0;
                while( $i <= 5 ){
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='users[]' value='{$i}' >";
                    $i++;
                }
                echo "<input type='button' name='update' class='button' value='Update' />";
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkAddress()
{
    if (document.querySelector('form[name="frmUser"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {
        alert("Success! (form would be submitted here)");
        //document.frmUser.action = "edit_user.php";
        //document.frmUser.submit();
    } else {
        alert("You must select at least one checkbox");
    }
}
</script>      
</head>

<body>

<div class="form-style-1">
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<?php
$i=0;
while($i<=5){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
<input type="button" name="update" class="button" value="Update" onClick="checkAddress(this);" />
<?php
$i++;}
?>
</form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: here is my Updated Code.